# How to change a font object without creating a new one?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a font sampler program with the swing GUI for my java class. The idea is to have an input field, three drop down menus for the font, the style, and the point size, and a display button which replaces the text field with whatever you typed and using the selected dropdown items.
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHy67.png). I haven't added the actionlisteners yet. I'm trying to figure out how I can create a font object once the display button is pressed, instead of creating a new font object for every possible combination? Kinda lost.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Fonts extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    JTextField inputLine;
    JButton displayButton;
    String inputText, outputText = "";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    
        Fonts f = new Fonts();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public Fonts()
    {
        setSize(400, 200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        inputLine = new JTextField(16);

        
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        
        displayButton = new JButton("Display");
        displayButton.addActionListener(this);
        JLabel input = new JLabel("Input:");

        inputPanel.add(input);
        inputPanel.add(inputLine);
        add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        String[] fonts = {"Arial", "Times New Roman", "Verdana", "Rockwell", "Franklin Gothic"};
        final JComboBox<String> font = new JComboBox<String>(fonts);
        font.addActionListener(this);
        
        String[] styles = {"None", "Bold", "Italic", "Bold and Italic"};
        final JComboBox<String> style = new JComboBox<String>(styles);
        style.addActionListener(this);
        
        String[] pointSizes = {"9", "10", "12", "14", "16", "24", "32"};
        final JComboBox<String> pointSize = new JComboBox<String>(pointSizes);
        pointSize.addActionListener(this);
    
        selectionPanel.add(font);
        selectionPanel.add(style);
        selectionPanel.add(pointSize);
        add(selectionPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        buttonPanel.add(displayButton);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        inputLine.setEditable(true);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 12);
        
        if(e.getSource()==displayButton)
        {
            inputLine.setFont(f1);
        }
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Font` class has no setters, the best you can do is make use of the `deriveFont` methods

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html

Answer (score 2):

The existing [Font](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) object size cant be changed. One way to achieve a similar effect is to use the `deriveFont(size)` method which will create a new almost identical Font that is a different size.

```
Font changeFont = myFont.deriveFont(value);
```

Note:`value` is float and not an int.

Comment: this is good. how can i do the same thing for the font name and style?

Comment: @Tactix You consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html)